# What is Just Intonation in detailed terms, and how can I notate it?

Tags: notation, harmony, just-intonation, microtonality

I've recently caught a great interest in the use of microtonal music through Just Intonation because of an artist I'm sure you've heard of recently, Jacob Collier. There a point in one of his songs where he used Just Intonation to shift from the key of *E Major* to the key of *G Half-Sharp Major* with only four chords. It absolutely astonished me.

I know there's some sort of correlation between Microtones and Harmony with the key being Just intonation, but I need a deeper understanding of it, as well as how to notate it into my music. Can someone please help? Thank you!!

Comment: Welcome to the site! You might try checking the [tag:just-intonation] and [tag:microtonality] tags "learn more" section for a little basic info if answers here don't get you anywhere *(disclaimer: okay, fine, I wrote them both)*. Have a good one!

Comment: Can you link to the song, or identify the chords?  Without context, I'm struggling to imagine how G half-sharp major would be more than about 1/4 semitone below equal-tempered G sharp, and just-intonation G sharp is already about 1/8 semitone below equal-tempered G sharp.  In other words, I suspect that the claims may be exaggerated or sensationalized.

Comment: @user45266 thank you for the welcome and the help! I'll give them a look!

Comment: @phoog I know which song OP is referring to, it's ["In the Bleak Midwinter"](https://youtu.be/mPZn4x3uOac?t=250) at about 4:15 if you want to investigate.

Comment: @phoog https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPZn4x3uOac the shift is from about 4:14 to 4:26. I've come across multiple videos pointing out that it's shifted into a microtonal key (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xd54l8gfi7M). Jacob Collier pointed it out himself too (16:45 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vrhKI7JHQc&t=1005s) and even pointed out the chords, but they didnt help me really UNDERSTAND, you know?

Comment: @user45266 and DC 'Dusk' King thanks.  That helps a lot.  This is very advanced and, if you listen carefully to Collier's words, you'll notice that he's _stretching_ just intonation to achieve his goal.  I have some advice that might help here.  I've voted to reopen the question because notation is the least of your worries at this point; you want to work toward understanding before you worry about writing.

Comment: The main issue here is a desire for understanding; the question about notation is secondary.  I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @phoog Thanks! Is reopening something that I do sense it's my question? Or something a mod or admin here has to do? I'm new, I dont know how everything works completely lol

Comment: Well I cast the second vote to reopen, of five needed, and no more votes have been cast since then.  The most efficient way to get your question answered at this point is probably to ask a new question without mentioning notation.

Comment: @phoog Noted, will do, thank you! Do you want me to send you a link to the new question when it's up?